# $timeout after method completion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout

i am using `$timeout` to call a function after completion of 1st function with **3 seconds delay**  but the problem is my method is taking completing

> for e.g(sometimes in 2 sec, 3 sec and sometime it is taking 4/5 seconds)

and my second function is being called before 1st function,

what is the possible ways to prevent this,

is there any way to set time on timeout dynamically,

i want to call my second function only after my first

Below is my code

```
    $scope.otherTipChecker();
    $rootScope.$emit("Loader", { loaded: true });
    $timeout(function () {
        $rootScope.$emit("OverrideTipDetail", {
            OverrideTipDetail: $scope.TipDetail
        });
        $("#tipEditModal").modal('hide');
        $rootScope.$emit("Loader", { loaded: false });
    }, 5000);
```

Comment: It would be better if you show us that piece of code first

Comment: Why you are not using `promise` for same. $timeout is not a optimal solution

Comment: update my Question

Comment: You need asynchronous callbacks; use `$q` service and work with promises. [`$q.defer()`](https://toddmotto.com/promises-angular-q#qdefer) object would delay the execution of another function until the first one finishes (if you need multiple functions to be chained one after another, use `$q.all()`)

Comment: Where is your _"first"_ function, after which completion, you want to invoke second function with delay? Is it `$scope.otherTipChecker();` or response to   `$rootScope.$emit("Loader", { loaded: true });`?

Answer (score 0):

Adding timeout is just a workaround. You need to implement promises. For more info read from below.

[Using promises in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)